# gzip.open("file.tar.gz", "rb") vs. tarfile.open("file.tar.gz"); extractall()

Tags: python, gzip, tarfile

Assuming I have one file - `'file.txt'` tarred and gzipped, what is the difference between:

```
    with tarfile.open('file.tar.gz') as tar:
        tar.extractall()
        with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
            x =  f.read()
```

and

```
    with gzip.open('file.tar.gz', 'rb') as f:
        x =  f.read()
```

In the 1st I get the output with no strange hex characters, that do appear in the 2nd. Does the `f.read` inside the `gzip` reads the actual `.tar` file instead of reading the plain file and those characters are the tar-files headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct assumption.
Tar simply glues files together without compression, while gzip can only compress single files.
You‘re reading the tar after decompression with gzip.open

Comment: Is there a function (my_tar_gz) that does something like `tar -xvzf` so I could do `with my_tar_gz(`file.tar.gz`) as f: f.read()`?